# cat/Xargs/command VS for/bash/command

Tags: c, bash, fork, for-loop, xargs

The page 38 of the book Linux 101 Hacks suggests:

```
cat url-list.txt | xargs wget –c
```

I usually do:

```
for i in `cat url-list.txt`
   do
      wget -c $i
   done
```

Is there some thing, other than length, where the xargs-technique is superior to the old good for-loop-technique in bash?

**Added**

The [C source code](http://cvsweb.de.netbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c?rev=HEAD) seems to have only one fork. In contrast, **how many forks have the bash-combo?** Please, elaborate on  the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Rationale section of [a UNIX manpage for `xargs`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html). (Interestingly this section doesn't appear in the OS X BSD version of `xargs`, nor in the GNU version.)

> The classic application of the xargs
>   utility is in conjunction with the
>   find utility to reduce the number of
>   processes launched by a simplistic use
>   of the find -exec combination. The
>   xargs utility is also used to enforce
>   an upper limit on memory required to
>   launch a process. With this basis in
>   mind, this volume of POSIX.1-2008
>   selected only the minimal features
>   required.

In your follow-up, you ask how many forks the other version will have. [Jim already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282697/cat-xargs-command-vs-for-bash-command/1282713#1282713): one per iteration. How many iterations are there? It's impossible to give an exact number, but easy to answer the general question. How many lines are there in your url-list.txt file?

There are other some other considerations. `xargs` requires extra care for filenames with spaces or other no-no characters, and `-exec` has an option (`+`), that groups processing into batches. So, not everyone prefers `xargs`, and perhaps it's not best for all situations.

See these links:

- http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2005-March/006255.html
- http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/05/find-exec-vs-xargs.html

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` is designed to process multiple inputs for each process it forks. A shell script with a `for` loop over its inputs must fork a new process for each input. Avoiding that per-process overhead can give an `xargs` solution a significant performance enhancement.

Comment: You mean xargs is only for performance? Hard to believe. There must be somethingg else with it.

Comment: It's also somewhat shorter to type.

And has a big label that says "don't panic"

Comment: And to be serious: process creation isn't very cheap. With today's fast processors it's not noticeable, but go back 10-15 years, and you can see why xargs was a preferred solution.

Comment: "only for performance?" Don't forget that `xargs` also handles large numbers of arguments for commands that can't.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider:

```
xargs -I'{}' wget -c '{}' < url-list.txt
```

but wget provides an even better means for the same:

```
wget -c -i url-list.txt
```

With respect to the xargs versus loop consideration, i prefer xargs when the meaning and implementation are relatively "simple" and "clear", otherwise, i use loops.

Answer (score 4):

xargs will also allow you to have a huge list, which is not possible with the "for" version because the shell uses command lines limited in length.

Comment: This is one of the only compelling reasons I've herd, assuming its correct and not obsolete information.

Answer (score 2):

instead of GNU/Parallel i prefer using xargs' built in parallel processing. Add -P to indicate how many forks to perform in parallel. As in...

```
 seq 1 10 | xargs -n 1 -P 3 echo
```

would use 3 forks on 3 different cores for computation.  This is supported by modern GNU Xargs.  You will have to verify for yourself if using BSD or Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your internet connection you may want to use GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ to run it in parallel.

```
cat url-list.txt | parallel wget -c
```

Answer (score 0):

One advantage I can think of is that, if you have lots of files, it could be slightly faster since you don't have as much overhead from starting new processes.

I'm not really a bash expert though, so there could be other reasons it's better (or worse).