# TFS Git assignment on what level (Project Team folder etc)

Tags: git, tfs

Given the typical TFS view, what is the most granular level at which I can have a Git project as opposed to TFVC?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vFeJ.jpg) [image]

From my understanding I can have a Git collection and then a traditional TFVC collection correct?

I also take it I can have a Git Team project in one collection and then have a TFVC Team project in the same collection, is that true also?

What about on the folder level , or am i limited to the type of version control that I choose higher up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2013 you cannot have both TFVC and Git in the same Project.

You may create multiple Git repositories in a Team Project, but only one is the default for Visual Studio, that is you have to add them explicitly.

To organize this repositories you can apply two Git patterns: [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856810/migrating-from-tfs-to-git-shared-projects-to-nuget) or [subtrees](http://blog.nwcadence.com/git-subtrees/). In both cases the support you get from Visual Studio or TFS Build is limited, expect some manual work.

You have no fine control on Git repositories in TFS, at most you can control permission on a branch. The scenario is to let any developer to work on branches, but only a benevolent dictator controls merges on `master`.

Comment: but in the same collection I can have a TFVC and then a Git project correct?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that Git support is evolving at a fast pace, e.g. 2013.4 will get Pull request, so annoyance will probably a short-term issue, if you are able to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Giulio it was very helpful