# Get Git statistics about line contributions within specific directories

Tags: git

I would like to see statistics telling me which authors have contributed how many lines *within a given directory*.

[git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) and some other similar tools exist, but I am having trouble figuring out if I can use them (or anything else) to restrict my statistics to a given directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git shortlog -s -- $1 | cut -c8- | while read i
do
    git log --author="$i" --pretty=tformat: --numstat -- $1 \
    | awk -v name="$i" '{ add += $1; subs += $2; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "%s: added lines: %s removed lines: %s total lines: %s\n", name, add, subs, loc }'
done
```

call it **loc.sh**
and then run: loc.sh [directory/file]

The output would be something like this:

> Name1: added lines: 10757 removed lines: 49 total lines: 10708
>   Nmae2:  added lines: 1193 removed lines: 94255 total lines: -93062

see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592866/git-how-to-estimate-a-contribution-of-a-person-to-my-project-in-terms-of-added) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Does this restrict the output to a single directory within the repository, or will the stats relate to the whole repository? If it does not, can you make it? — that's one of the keys to the question. If it does, which part does that?

Comment: Yes it does. When you run the script loc.sh give it as an argument in cmdline the desired file/directory. (You can see in the script itself "-- $1" this makes the git command filter on the required file/dir)

Comment: Confirmed! Thanks --- now I'll have to research the way you're using bash so I can better understand it.

Answer (score -2):

check this CLI tool (https://www.npmjs.com/package/whodid)

```
$ npm install whodid -g
```

then, go to your project directory and just type this

```
$ cd my-project
$ whodid
```

and also you can get result as JSON

```
$ whodid author --as-json=true
```

and if you want, not recommanded, but you can include lines in merge commit.

```
$ whodid author --include-merge=true
```

and if you feel someones score is too much, you can check the reason with 'heavy' sub-command.

```
$ whodid heavy --num2=20 --author="jeff <jeff@xahoo.com>"
```