# Show the percentage of lines in the latest revision of a git repository by committer?

Tags: git

Is there a command or tool to show the percentage of lines in the latest revision of a git repository by committer? Mostly out of intellectual curiosity, but it may be useful for something sooner or later...

---

**Update:** It looks like [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589731/git-blame-statistics/4590487#4590487) gets me 95% there - it returns the line count, how can I turn that into percentages?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `git help shortlog`, it should put you close enough to what you want.

Comment: The OP wants to know about actual lines of content per committer, not commits per committer.