# How to export all code from git committed by particular user?

Tags: git, github, export

I need to document contribution to the project made by a particular user. Code is stored in github. I need to list all the code he has submitted, i don't need intermediate commits, only the final version.

Is there an easy way to export all his code? Thanks

Update: I need to know which lines of code written by a particular user made it to the final version of the app. What was his contribution to get it properly documented. Not the list of commits, but the code he has contributed.

So as the end result it should be all code submitted by this developer.

Comment: This may help you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Comment: I think you might need to be more clear about what you mean. The code itself, or just commit messages.  What if they have touched just one character of a file -do you want the entire file, or just the diffs...... much more information needed.

Comment: What i need is a code listing as the end result. I want to know which lines of code in the final version were written by a particular developer. E.g. I need to know what lines of code were contributed by this developer. Thanks

Comment: And thanks for anonymously downvoting my question whoever you are, my friend. If you need clarification, why don't you just ask. If you don't like my question, why don't you explain yourself. This is a problem i'm facing and i'm looking for a solution, not some anonymous judging.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to know which lines of code written by a particular user made it to the final version of the app. What was his contribution to get it properly documented

You can use **[`git blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)** for that.

For applying git blame on multiple files, see "[Git: Blame Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687302/6309)";

```
$  git ls-tree --name-only -z -r HEAD|egrep -z -Z -E '\.(cc|h|cpp|hpp|c|txt)$' \
   |xargs -0 -n1 git blame --line-porcelain|grep "^author "|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr
```

You might have to adapt that in order to grep and show the exact information you need, but `git blame` is made to show the lines contributed by a specific author.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --author=your_name_here > log.txt`

Comment: Won't that just list all the author's commits?  Now I think the question is almost impossible to answer, but I don't think this is what they are looking for, he says 'export all code'.

Comment: Yeah that is impossible.  This is the best I know how to do.

Comment: Thanks, but it lists user commits, i'm interested in listing submitted code