# git blame on windows reports "fatal: no such path <path> in HEAD"

Tags: git, git-blame, git-for-windows

When I run git blame on a file in a folder e,g,:

`git blame Foo/FileA.txt`

it returns

`fatal: no such path 'Foo/FileA.txt' in HEAD`

I can clearly see that this file exists on the file system, and other files in the same folder can be successfully blamed - so what is going on?

I'm posting this question and answer as it had me stumped for a while today, and I couldn't find a single answer that hit all of the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is due to renaming a parent folder on the file system with a new name that varies only by case - and some files were added in a commit occurring before the rename of the folder. Here is a repro, from a Powershell prompt:

```
mkdir C:\RenameProblem
cd C:\RenameProblem
git init
mkdir foo
"FileA" > foo/FileA.txt
git add foo/FileA.txt
git commit -m "Add FileA"
```

Then in windows explorer, rename directory "foo" to "Foo" and then continue in Powershell with:

```
"FileB" > Foo/FileB.txt
git add Foo/FileB.txt
git commit -m "Add FileB"
```

At this point, `git blame /Foo/FileA.txt` (which tab completion will generate since the folder has renamed) will fail with the no such path error, whereas `git blame /Foo/FileB.txt` or even `git blame /foo/FileA.txt` will succeed.

Futhermore, a call to `git ls-files Foo` will list only `FileB.txt` and `git ls-files foo` will list only `FileA.txt`. Not a great place to be on Windows.

In my case, I had a large number of files split between the two versions of the folder name.

You can solve this by renaming the file with `git mv`:

```
git mv foo/FileA.txt Foo/FileA.txt
git commit -am "Rename foo to Foo"
```

If you need to rename a lot of files, use a bit of Powershell (also, note that `git mv` has a `-n` switch to do a "what-if" dry run, so you can check your rename is correct):

```
git ls-files foo | % { (& git mv $_ $('F' + $_.Substring(1))) }
```

The above uses `git ls-files` to get a list of files in the problem "foo" folder, pipes this into a "ForEach" (`%` is the shortcut for that) and then executes `git mv` for each file supplying the original name (`$_`) and the new name of 'F' and the rest of the file name (`'F' + $_.Substring(1))`)

Comment: I'm eager to try this answer, except I don't know what file (directory) has been renamed. I'm getting `fatal: no such path 'HEAD' in HEAD`, trying to use the script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687302/1168342

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that the file or a containing directory are a symbolic link. You can use `ls -l` to verify this is the case. Try to blame the file in its original location instead.

Answer (score 0):

Entering the terminal from the file directory and then blaming it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

For me that was Rider showing in the console. Restarting Rider helped.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35480247)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).