# When I try to annotate git history Intellij show error:fatal: no such path in HEAD

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Who knows how to resolve this issue? [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077735/13576700

Comment: Do you have submodules in your project by any chance? Please check whether they are not listed under "Unregistered root" in Preferences | Version Control

Comment: The problem was with semilink. I reimported my project and choose real files(packages). 
Additionally in intellij IDEA  Settings->Version Control-> I added my project.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. And the issue was file naming.
Other dev changed file name from all lowercase to first letter uppercase. So check from repo what naming is expected and update your path naming accordingly.
Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was apparently happening with only a few of my projects, not all. As per the answer & some valuable comments, I couldn't find anything fishy with my setup. The git repo was available under `Preferences | Version Control` & with no issues with a symlink (as I wasn't using any).

Finally:

1. I had to "Remove from Recent Projects..." as you can see in the attached screenshot
2. Deleted the `.idea/` directory from the corrupted project

An now I'm able to use the Git "Annotation" using PHPStorm

[image]