# Find which developers' code was changed by a commit?

Tags: git, bash, diff, blame

Is there a way using git to find out which developers' code was changed by a particular commit?

The process would look something like:
Take a commit SHA, get each changed line in the parent commit `git diff SHA^!`, group them by the author of the line (`git blame`) and then order them by number of lines and list it out like

```
Commit SHA### updated code written by the following developers:
Jane Smythe (23 lines)
Rickard Strauss (8 lines)
```

I am thinking of using this to print to the console when committing (*the following devs code were modified, make sure to tag them in your PR*), it could even be potentially integrated with Bitbucket/Git to automatically tag devs whose code is being changed or email them etc etc.

I found [this gist using python that appears to do something similar](https://gist.github.com/5263/8752519), but is going into a separate language other than bash/git necessary for this?

Comment: I'm just going to put this out there - this is the first good use of blame I've seen, and I feel bad to have not ever thought of it before.

Comment: "is going into a separate language other than bash/git necessary for this?" - I'm not sure if bash alone is powerful enough, but in standard git installation you could also find `perl`, and even if you happen to have minimal windows installation there is `awk`.

Comment: Realistically I can rely on `node` existing on my whole team always, but a universal solution is preferred if I'm talking about it in public ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use git-diff-blame https://github.com/dmnd/git-diff-blame

And you could filter by commit sha

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that reliably, because git would need to distinguish between added and edited lines which doesn't work.

A good approach would be to take the percentage of contributions in the file - before the commit - and address those in the PR which contributed most. This is what github is doing btw.

Comment: Could we look at the author of each line that was removed in the diff?

Comment: Where is github doing this?

Comment: @Damon github is recommending those authors for a review. (Upper right corner at the PR page)

Comment: @Damon As soon as the change gets non trivial, meaning inserting some lines here, deleting some lines there, the name of the author of a certain line number gets more and more useless.

Comment: Haven't worked with bitbucket too much. If they don't ship that feature, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4589731/171318