How to summarize my contributions to a project?
I've just completed a project for a client who has asked me to summarize my contributions to a project.  What git (or GitHub) commands would point me to the bits I've changed in the main branch?
I don't need strict diffs -- I just want to know the files (and perhaps dates) of files I've changed.

Git is about commits, not files.

Sounds like a job for git blame.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687302/3216427 for a way to get the git blame output on your whole repo, although you'll want different analysis than the counting steps done afterwards in that answer.

Assuming you started working on the project 2024-01-01 you could run something like
git log --since 2024-01-01 --author="Your Name" --name-only --format=format:"" main | sort -u

in order to get a list of all the files you have edited.
For more sophisticated statistics I think you need to look into a dedicated git statistics program. There are some listed here.

My buddy Chad JeePeeTee suggested:
git log --author="Your Name" --stat

as one of several useful output formats.  But I'll also checkout @joanis's suggestion about blame.
